# 301 Redirects for Non SXA site in a Sitecore SXA instance

Tags: sxa, redirect

I have a Sitecore instance with both SXA and Non SXA sites. I want to implement 301 redirects for both the sites. For the SXA site, I'm able to do it through the SXA Redirect Map but how do I perform the redirects for the Non SXA site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirect behavior in SXA only applies to sites managed by SXA.

Consider the options typical of a non-SXA implementation but be aware of the risks and limitations of each.

### Examples

- Redirect in CDN/Proxy - difficult to apply for many 1-to-1. Cloudflare for example limits the number of available page rules.
- IIS Rewrite module - Low complexity for large list of redirects. Requires web.config update.
- 301 Redirect modules for Sitecore - may not play well with SXA. May require custom development.

The most compatible solution would be the IIS Redirect and the easiest to remove once the other sites migrate to SXA.

### Update

Another recommendation is the following module

- https://github.com/iamandycohen/UrlRewrite

Answer (score 1):

For performance wise IIS redirect are good. Some references for Sitecore redirects:

https://github.com/thecadams/301RedirectModule
https://buoctrenmay.com/2019/03/31/playing-around-with-sitecore-user-friendly-redirect-template/
https://github.com/davvves/UrlRewrite/blob/sc9update/Package/Url%20Rewrite%20for%20Sitecore%209.zip